# Passing arguments to a .cmd file in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a .cmd file which asks the user for an input, based on which further steps are performed. I am trying to write a program to automate this process in C# such that command prompt runs in the background(without popping up to the user/eliminating all user interaction) and the arguments get passed. I have referred to multiple answers, however did not find a solution. I have already referred the links below.

[Passing cmd line arguments to specific method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687332/passing-cmd-line-arguments-to-specific-method)

[Passing Cmd Command to C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426542/passing-cmd-command-to-c-sharp-application)

[Passing c# command line arguments in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905799/passing-c-sharp-command-line-arguments-in-a-batch-file)

It would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You're searching for the wrong thing. You need to look for something like "c# console redirect", e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848271/redirecting-standard-input-of-console-application It's not the console app arguments you need, it's the input stream.

Comment: if user input is simple, you can try to add an `echo` to command line

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Try edit your bat/cmd for receive arguments thought in C#:

- **`args[]`**   in   **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)**   is   **`%1,%2,%n...`**   in   **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

**2)** You need edit your bat/cmd to receive your C# arguments:

- **`Console.ReadLine()`**   in   **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)**    is   **`set /p some_var_by_input=`**   in   **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

  - Edit in the bat/cmd file, wherever you need:  **`set / p input_1 =" Enter some entry: "`**
  - Remove and add the appropriate treatment to your arguments:

    ```
    set /p input_1="Enter some input:"
    set input_1=%~1
    ```
  - If there is more than one argument, just increase like...

    ```
    set "input_2=%~2"
    set "input_n=%~n"
    ```

Here is sample **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code that are sending 2 arguments to a **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\batchfilename.bat", "\"1st\" \"2nd\"");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Obs.:** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** sources from [@T.S.Sathish](http://T.S.Sathish) [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123561/8177207)

---

- The bat file code using %1 & %2 arguments passed from C #:

  ---

```
@echo off 
%__APPDIR__%mode.com con: cols=60 lines=6
echo/
echo/  your arg_CS[0] == arg_bat[%%1] == %1
echo/  your arg_CS[1] == arg_bat[%%2] == %2
echo/ ________________________________________________________
echo/ Please, press any key for me got to go drink a coffe...
@%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul
```

---

- bat/cmd outputs:

  ---

[image]

---

> Option 2 : Hiding the console window, passing arguments and taking outputs

- This is an edit from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742287/8177207) /by [@Brian Rasmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38206/brian-rasmussen)

  ---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         var process = new Process();
         var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\batchfilename.bat", "\"1st_arg\" \"2nd_arg\" \"3rd_arg\"");
         startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
         startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         process.StartInfo = startinfo;
         process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, argsx) => Console.WriteLine(argsx.Data); // do whatever processing you need to do in this handler
         process.Start();
         process.BeginOutputReadLine();
         process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sub>This is based on my limited understanding of **English** so if that is not correct, sorry, and if possible, please let me know ...</sub>

---